# Por que una imagen recarga al cambiar el state en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Tengo el siguiente `state`:

```
this.state={
    objetivos:[],
    objetivo:null,
    unidades:[],
    fondofinancieros:[],
    users:[],
    cargar:true,
    view:{
        render:"index",
        index:0
    },
    form:{
        unidad:null,
        fondofinanciero:null,
        user:null
    },
    paginate:{
        activePage:1,
        itemsCountPerPage: 30,
        totalItemsCount:0,
        pageRangeDisplayed:5,
        textsearch:'',
    },
}
```

Luego en el render:

```
return (
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col col-md-4">
            <div className="x_panel" style={{position:"-webkit-sticky",position:"sticky","top":"70px"}}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2>Filtrar Por:</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="clearfix"></div>
                <SolicitudForm
                    form={this.state.form}
                    unidades={this.state.unidades}
                    fondofinancieros={this.state.fondofinancieros}
                    users={this.state.users}
                    onSearch={this.onSearch}
                    onChangeSelect={this.onChangeSelect}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <SolicitudList
            objetivos={this.state.objetivos}
            onChangeView={this.onChangeView}
        />
        <Pagination
          activePage={this.state.paginate.activePage}
          itemsCountPerPage={this.state.paginate.itemsCountPerPage}
          totalItemsCount={this.state.paginate.totalItemsCount}
          pageRangeDisplayed={this.state.paginate.pageRangeDisplayed}
          onChange={this.handlePageChange}
        />
    </div>
        )
```

El problema esta dentro de `SolicitudList`:

```
const SolicitudList=({objetivos,onChangeView})=>{
    return (
        <div className="col col-md-8">
            {
                objetivos.map((obj) => <TargetaSolicitud 
                                        key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)} 
                                        objetivo={obj}
                                        onChangeView={onChangeView}
                                        /> 
                            )
            }
        </div>
        )
}
```

Específicamente en `TargetaSolicitud` donde tengo el código para mostrar la imagen:

```
<img src={`${URL_BASE}/api/imagen_user/${objetivo.user==null?"user.png":objetivo.user.foto}?api_token=${API_TOKEN}`} title={objetivo.user==null?"": userFullname(objetivo.user)} />
```

El cual descarga una imagen de una api hecha en laravel.

Todo funciona hasta que utilizo la funcion `onChangeSelect` del componente `SolicitudForm`, que es el siguiente:

```
onChangeSelect(e,t){
    this.setState({

        form:{
            ...this.state.form,
            [t]:e    
        }
    })
}
```

El bug es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no es la única foto, ya que es una lista larga y todas se actualizan.

> Por qué pasa esto? como lo soluciono?

Comment: por que recarga la imagen? Deberia ser diferente la imagen cada que cambias los dropdown? Ese parpadeo que da la imagen es porque el state se modifica cuando se ejecuta el `onChangeSelect` y como `SolicitudList` esta en el render, todo se vulve a rerenderear.

Comment: @Isaac, Si puedes leer la funcion `onChangeSelect` eso te respondera todo.

Answer (score 0):

Es conjetura, pero tal vez tiene que verificar que el `state` ha cambiado antes de cambiarlo? Le sugiero lo siguiente:

```
onChangeSelect(e,t){
    if (this.state.form.t !== e) {
        // tal vez console.log(e) aqui tambien
        // para ver si `e` es objecto o primitivo.
        // ==== entre objectos solo funciona si refiere al 
        // mismo objeto en la memoria
        this.setState({
            form:{
                ...this.state.form,
                [t]:e    
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: pues no eso no funciona, ademas de que `t` toma el valor de : unidad ó fondofinanciero ó  user